# I am trying to import a virtual appliance. It concludes with a failure. What might me wrong?

Tags: import, segmentation-fault, google-compute-engine, instance, gcloud

I uploaded an ova file to my bucket. I open the Cloud Shell online terminal. I set region and zone successfully. Then I run the following command to start the import.

```
gcloud compute instances import adv-odi --source-uri=gs://memoconq/Win2012_64bit_DB_12c_ODI_12cVM.ova
```

The terminal output is following.

```
starting build "fa0e53a4-c211-4210-b35d-999c1499f65e"
[import-ovf] 2020-05-12T01:45:49Z Starting OVF import workflow.
[import-ovf] 2020-05-12T01:45:49Z Creating scratch bucket `advanced-odi-training-ovf-import-bkt-us-east1` in us-east1 region
[import-ovf] 2020-05-12T01:45:50Z Extracting gs://memoconq/Win2012_64bit_DB_12c_ODI_12cVM.ova OVA archive to gs://advanced-odi-training-ovf-import-bkt-us-east1/ovf-import-4xzzt/ovf
[import-ovf] 2020-05-12T01:45:50Z Extracting: Win2012_64bit_DB_12c_ODI_12cVM.ovf to gs://advanced-odi-training-ovf-import-bkt-us-east1/ovf-import-4xzzt/ovf/Win2012_64bit_DB_12c_ODI_12cVM.ovf
[import-ovf] 2020-05-12T01:45:50Z Extracting: Win2012_64bit_DB_12c_ODI_12cVM-disk001.vmdk to gs://advanced-odi-training-ovf-import-bkt-us-east1/ovf-import-4xzzt/ovf/Win2012_64bit_DB_12c_ODI_12cVM-disk001.vmdk
[import-ovf] 2020-05-12T01:53:30Z Extracting: Win2012_64bit_DB_12c_ODI_12cVM.mf to gs://advanced-odi-training-ovf-import-bkt-us-east1/ovf-import-4xzzt/ovf/Win2012_64bit_DB_12c_ODI_12cVM.mf
[import-ovf] 2020-05-12T01:53:30Z Found gs://advanced-odi-training-ovf-import-bkt-us-east1/ovf-import-4xzzt/ovf/Win2012_64bit_DB_12c_ODI_12cVM.ovf
[import-ovf] 2020-05-12T01:53:31Z Found gs://advanced-odi-training-ovf-import-bkt-us-east1/ovf-import-4xzzt/ovf/Win2012_64bit_DB_12c_ODI_12cVM-disk001.vmdk
[import-ovf] 2020-05-12T01:53:31Z Cleaning up.
[import-ovf] 2020/05/12 01:53:31 Deleting content of: gs://advanced-odi-training-ovf-import-bkt-us-east1/ovf-import-4xzzt/ovf/
[import-ovf] 2020-05-12T01:53:31Z Deleting gs://advanced-odi-training-ovf-import-bkt-us-east1/ovf-import-4xzzt/ovf/Win2012_64bit_DB_12c_ODI_12cVM-disk001.vmdk
[import-ovf] 2020-05-12T01:53:31Z Deleting gs://advanced-odi-training-ovf-import-bkt-us-east1/ovf-import-4xzzt/ovf/Win2012_64bit_DB_12c_ODI_12cVM.mf
[import-ovf] 2020-05-12T01:53:31Z Deleting gs://advanced-odi-training-ovf-import-bkt-us-east1/ovf-import-4xzzt/ovf/Win2012_64bit_DB_12c_ODI_12cVM.ovf
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_ovf_import:release" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 2
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.import) build fa0e53a4-c211-4210-b35d-999c1499f65e completed with status "FAILURE"
```

The following lines are added in the log.

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x12b4f56]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools/cli_tools/gce_ovf_import/ovf_utils.GetOSId(0xc000130230, 0xc00017aa60, 0xc000708050, 0x48, 0xc000130230)
    /workspace/cli_tools/gce_ovf_import/ovf_utils/ovf_utils.go:261 +0xe6
github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools/cli_tools/gce_ovf_import/ovf_importer.(*OVFImporter).setUpImportWorkflow(0xc0001d6000, 0x193fc1e, 0x1d, 0x5)
    /workspace/cli_tools/gce_ovf_import/ovf_importer/ovf_importer.go:431 +0x395
github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools/cli_tools/gce_ovf_import/ovf_importer.(*OVFImporter).Import(0xc0001d6000, 0xc0001d6000, 0x0, 0x0)
    /workspace/cli_tools/gce_ovf_import/ovf_importer/ovf_importer.go:474 +0x6f
main.runImport(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /workspace/cli_tools/gce_ovf_import/main.go:115 +0xbf
github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools/cli_tools/common/utils/logging/service.(*Logger).runWithServerLogging(0xc0000e6f50, 0x197b1f8, 0xc000549240, 0x0, 0xc00011a900, 0x0)
    /workspace/cli_tools/common/utils/logging/service/logger.go:220 +0xa0
github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools/cli_tools/common/utils/logging/service.RunWithServerLogging(0x191e66b, 0xe, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc00011a900, 0x0, 0xc000549240, 0x197b1f8, 0x1, 0xc000076058)
    /workspace/cli_tools/common/utils/logging/service/logger.go:257 +0x86
main.main()
    /workspace/cli_tools/gce_ovf_import/main.go:133 +0xe4
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_ovf_import:release" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 2
```

Is there a way to overcome this error? Or are there alternative methods to import an ova file?

Comment: Did you perform basic checks before starting: the source VMDK file is unencrypted, configured with MBR boot, without UEFI? Did `import_precheck.exe` exit without warnings?

Comment: I learned a different method to create a vm from ova file and run as a nested instance inside a Compute Engine VM instance: [Enabling Nested Virtualization for VM Instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances)

Comment: Did a nested instance worked for you, have you achieved the goal in the end?

Comment: Yes, it worked.